# Saving text filename to database using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, select, insert

I have a question and I need your help..
is it possible to create a application that will get all the `.txt` in a directory then save its filename to database and if there's a validation for the filename will not save twice on the database.

got my code here:

```
const path = require('path')

//mysql Connecion
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "sms"
});

//con checking if the database is connected
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    //watchfile directory if there's new added file
    var chokidar = require('chokidar'); 
    var watcher = chokidar.watch('texts/', {ignored: /^\./, persistent: true});

    //for getting the filename only
    var fs = require('fs');
    var testFolder = 'texts/';

    watcher.on('add', function(filePath) {

        var filename = path.basename(filePath);

        var selectSql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM txtfilename WHERE filename="${filename}"';
        con.query(selectSql, (err, results, fields) => {
                // TODO: Catch the error
                var matchingEntriesCount = results

                if (matchingEntriesCount === 0) {
                    // TODO: Do your insert query
                    console.log('File', results, 'has been added');
                    var insertsql = "INSERT INTO txtfilename (filename) VALUES ('"+ results +"')";
                    con.query(insertsql, function (err, result) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        console.log("1 record inserted");
                    });
                }
        });
    });
    watcher.on('unlink', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been removed');});
});
```

my code can now read all of the files that will save on the directory but I'm have a trouble on `SELECT` and `INSERT`.

I want to use select for validation. for not to insert a same filename on the database.

last is the insert. i want to insert every new filename that will save to the directory.

hopefully someone can help me.

I'm just a newbie to NodeJS

Comment: Do you want to add the filename or the full (or relative) path?

Comment: just the filename.. then after that i will call all the filenames then saves all the filenames content and merge into one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I see is that you need to get the filename only from the `path` returned from the watcher. I'll use the [path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path) package `basename` method for that.

```
const path = require('path')

...

watcher.on('add', function(filePath) {
    var filename = path.basename(filePath);
    ....
```

Then you have make to count the entries in your table that matches this filename.

```
    var selectSql = `SELECT count(*) AS matchingEntriesCount FROM txtfilename WHERE filename="${filename}"`

    con.query(selectSql, (err, results, fields) => {
        // TODO: Catch the error
        var matchingEntriesCount = results[0].matchingEntriesCount

        if (matchingEntriesCount === 0) {
            // TODO: Do your insert query
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Pierre, on the filePath should i insert the file directory?.. because right now there's an error... TypeError: `path.basename is not a function`

Comment: Oups! Change `path` to `filePath` in `watcher.on('add', function(filePath) {`. I updated my answer.

Comment: thank you.. right now I add my insert query but there's no result showing on my git bash.. I'll update my code

Comment: @RiyotaMiyagi There was a problem in my code (the last part) in the way I was getting the `count(*)` value. I fixed it! I should have tested my code before submitting an answer.

Comment: wow.. thanks man.. this really helps me... I appreciate your effort... :)

Comment: also is there a way to automatically save all of the new file on the directory `texts/`

Comment: No problem :) The watcher detects files in the *texts* directory. As I see it they already are saved in there if the watcher sees them. Maybe I didn't quite understand. However, you might want to ask a new question for this issue.

Comment: thank you... also there's one more error that I encounter... its said `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
`

Comment: Might mean that there is an error thrown by the query that you are not catching. You need to replace the `// TODO: Catch the error` by actual code.